# What does a JQuery selector on HTML markup do?

Tags: jquery

I noticed that

```
  $( "<a></a>" ).text( "wow" );
```

will put the text `"wow"` inside the a tags and result in

```
<a>wow</a>
```

I can't find this documented. Where else can I use this? Is it only available within `text()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is indeed documented. It's [the second form](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) of the `$()` function.

The code in your question creates a new `<a>` element, then sets its inner text to `wow`. You can create DOM element trees from arbitrary HTML markup that way, and all the jQuery methods, not only `text()`, can be called on the resulting object.

Answer (score 2):

The

```
$("<a></a>")
```

returns a jQuery object and you can call most of the jQuery functions. For instance you can do this:

```
$("<a></a>").attr("id","anchor1").css({color:"#ff0000"}).appendTo("#parent");
```

You can simplify this a bit by just doing

```
$("<a>").
```

Answer (score 1):

It is actually parsing the HTML element  and then applying the text operation to it.

You would be able to do the same thing with any html string, take for instance:

`$("<input type='text' value='Hello World!' />").val()` will return Hello World.

The selector will parse any HTML passed, this is how you can take a standard click event and apply $(this) which is a selector on the containing HTML element that the event was fired on.

Hope this clarifies your confusion!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a selector, it's an element creator.

Putting valid HTML instead `$()` creates that HTML.  The call to `.text()` thereafter is of course separate, and changes the inner content of the just-created element.